# Installing lighttpd on CentOS 6.3 yum 404 errors

Tags: centos, yum, lighttpd, centos6, epel

I have a CentOS 6.3 x86_64 server and I am trying to install lighttpd.  I have installed the EPEL repo on the server using the following:

```
 rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
```

I then attempted to install lighttpd using the following command:

```
yum install lighttpd lighttpd-fastcgi
```

The command outputs the following:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * Webmin: download.webmin.com
 * base: ftp.usf.edu
 * epel: mirrors.rit.edu
 * extras: ftp.usf.edu
 * updates: ftp.usf.edu
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package lighttpd.x86_64 0:1.4.31-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: lighttpd-1.4.31-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libldap-2.3.so.0()(64bit) for package: lighttpd-1.4.31-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liblber-2.3.so.0()(64bit) for package: lighttpd-1.4.31-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: lighttpd-1.4.31-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package lighttpd-fastcgi.x86_64 0:1.4.31-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: spawn-fcgi for package: lighttpd-fastcgi-1.4.31-1.el5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-openldap.x86_64 1:2.3.43-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-17.el6.centos.2 will be installed
---> Package spawn-fcgi.x86_64 0:1.6.3-1.el5 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

========================================================================================================================
 Package                         Arch                  Version                                Repository           Size
========================================================================================================================
Installing:
 lighttpd                        x86_64                1.4.31-1.el5                           epel                331 k
 lighttpd-fastcgi                x86_64                1.4.31-1.el5                           epel                 45 k
Installing for dependencies:
 compat-openldap                 x86_64                1:2.3.43-2.el6                         base                159 k
 openssl098e                     x86_64                0.9.8e-17.el6.centos.2                 base                761 k
 spawn-fcgi                      x86_64                1.6.3-1.el5                            epel                 16 k

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================
Install       5 Package(s)

Total size: 1.3 M
Total download size: 391 k
Installed size: 3.7 M
```

It then tries to download the packages:

```
Downloading Packages:
http://mirrors.rit.edu/epel/6/x86_64/lighttpd-1.4.31-1.el5.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404"
Trying other mirror.
```

It is trying to download lighttpd-1.4.31-1.el5.x86_64.rpm (the el5 rpm) when the actual real file is http://mirrors.rit.edu/epel/6/x86_64/lighttpd-1.4.31-1.el6.x86_64.rpm the el6 rpm.  How do I fix this issue on the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just after posting the question I found the solution.  Running the following command fixed the issue:

```
yum clean all
```

Comment: next time run yum update before a yum install

Comment: I did run yum update before and that didn't help.  It seems yum clean all did fix the issue though.  Still not sure why though.

Comment: Probably because you had EPEL 5 repo on the box at some point in the past. Welcome to Server Fault. Remember to accept your answer. :)

Comment: Thanks!  Yes I have a feeling that I installed the EPEL 5 repo accidentally before this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Instead of letting yum download and install that rpm, download it yourself

```
wget http://mirrors.rit.edu/epel/6/x86_64/lighttpd-1.4.31-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

and then let yum install it

```
yum localinstall lighttpd-1.4.31-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Yes but wouldn't it be best to get the repo working so that I receive updates?  I did fix the issue myself just after posting the question, see my answer.  Looks like something was broken and yum clean all fixed it.  Thanks!